# Can you change the skill auto battle uses?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

Is it possible to change the abilities that my characters use during auto battle?

For instance, Bell only use Firebolt but it would be better for him to use Rapid Slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, no. Auto battle favors skill use over regular attacking. That said, it tries to be smart about the skill use. For Example, if your party is at good health, your healer won't use healing. Or if there is only one enemy, your unit likely won't use the aoe skill.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer.

Comment: From what I have seen nothing stops them from using the limit break.

Comment: the ultimate skill will always be used if it can, but what I meant was while the autobattle will always pick skills over plain attack, if the unit as a single target skill and an aoe skill (like Aiz, for example). She will use the single target if there is only one enemy alive when the turn is set.